# Addition of Audit Trails to a SaaS Platform

Tags: cloud, saas, audit, audit-logging

I am trying to add compliance mechanisms to a SaaS platform. I wanted to add audit trails in it. Well, the first thing I have decided is to log all the successful/un-successful attempts in authorization module. Then I need to audit all the alterations and additions and deletions along with their points of origin. 
I want your help in how I should go about it? Should I use a reverse proxy? 
I found that aspect oriented programming can be used as as well. 
Where to store all this logged data? (in a database or some other form)

As you might see I am not very clear about anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could very well integrate Microsoft Enterprise library kind of proven and highly configurable systems to take care of the handling of the cross-cutting concerns.

Further more, with respect to auditing each of the alterations or updations in the system, you should be a bit cautious not to slow down the entire system.

With respect to the storage of the audited data, it should be configurable on a tenant basis so that one tenant can have his audit detail in a separate db or in a log file as such and also the level of auditing also to be considered.

IMHO, there does not seem to be a single package that could work out for your requirements but you have to fiddle with the proven libraries like EL and then use them to suit your requirements.